# Safe-CLI not working on BSC

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, gnosis-safe, bsc

I have a contract wallet created by 1.1.1 manually on BSC. It seems the only way to interact with it is through [SAFE-CLI](https://github.com/5afe/safe-cli) (Command Line Interface).

However, **I find the CLI package seems down on BSC that I could not interact with it.**(**For contract wallet on ETH is fine**)
How could I fix it? It seems first we have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/codespace/.python/current/bin/safe-cli", line 5, in <module>
    from safe_cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args()
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 1826, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 1859, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 2071, in _parse_known_args
    stop_index = consume_positionals(start_index)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 2027, in consume_positionals
    take_action(action, args)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 1920, in take_action
    argument_values = self._get_values(action, argument_strings)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 2451, in _get_values
    value = self._get_value(action, arg_string)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/argparse.py", line 2484, in _get_value
    result = type_func(arg_string)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/prompt_parser.py", line 70, in to_checksummed_ethereum_address
    return Web3.toChecksumAddress(address)
AttributeError: type object 'Web3' has no attribute 'toChecksumAddress'. Did you mean: 'to_checksum_address'?
```

Then if I modify in prompt_parser.py, I got new code=1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract/utils.py", line 111, in call_contract_function
    output_data = w3.codec.decode(output_types, return_data)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/codec.py", line 149, in decode
    return decoder(stream)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 128, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 174, in decode
    yield decoder(stream)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 128, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 143, in decode
    start_pos = decode_uint_256(stream)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 128, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 198, in decode
    raw_data = self.read_data_from_stream(stream)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 305, in read_data_from_stream
    raise InsufficientDataBytes(
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes
```

and

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/codespace/.python/current/bin/safe-cli", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    safe_cli = SafeCli()
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/main.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.safe_operator = SafeOperator(safe_address, node_url)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/safe_cli/operators/safe_operator.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.safe_contract = self.safe.contract
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.8/lib/python3.10/functools.py", line 981, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gnosis/safe/safe.py", line 114, in contract
    version = v_1_3_0_contract.functions.VERSION().call()
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract/contract.py", line 283, in call
    return call_contract_function(
  File "/home/codespace/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract/utils.py", line 129, in call_contract_function
    raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not decode contract function call to VERSION with return data: b'', output_types: ['string']
```